# Querybuilder Inner Join returns too much in doctrine2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, doctrine-orm

This is my query in Symfony2-Project, using doctrine:

```
    $qb->select(array('r', 'fp', 'p'))
    ->from('Farmerguide\BackendBundle\Entity\Farmerproduct', 'fp')
    ->innerJoin('fp.product', 'p')
    ->innerJoin('p.rubric', 'r')
    ->andWhere('fp.farmer= :id')
    ->setParameter('id', $farmerId);
```

Information about the tables/entities:
Farmerproduct has a id, farmer_id and a product_id
product has a id, and rubric_id (product is some kind of a 'subdirectory' of rubric)

I want now all rubrics without anything else, for one farmer.
But I'm getting an error when I change the `select`-part, it says that it needs all of the `joined` Entitys to be selected...

Well, now I'm getting all joined information, so for 100 products of 1 farmer, I'm getting every product with rubric and with farmer (i don't know why i'm getting the farmer aswell..)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must select the root entity of your DQL query. Assuming you do not have bidirectional associations, it looks like following:

```
SELECT
    r
FROM
    Farmerguide\BackendBunle\Entity\Rubric r
WHERE
    r.id IN (
        SELECT
            r2.id
        FROM
            Farmerguide\BackendBundle\Entity\Farmerproduct fp
        JOIN
            fp.product p
        JOIN
            p.rubric r2
        WHERE
            fp.farmer = :id
    )
```

In `QueryBuilder` API, this looks like following:

```
$qb1 = $em->createQueryBuilder();
$qb2 = $em->createQueryBuilder();

$qb2
    ->select(array('r2.id'))
    ->from('Farmerguide\BackendBundle\Entity\Farmerproduct', 'fp')
    ->innerJoin('fp.product', 'p')
    ->innerJoin('p.rubric', 'r2')
    ->andWhere('fp.farmer= :id')

$qb1
    ->select('r')
    ->from('Farmerguide\BackendBunle\Entity\Rubric', 'r')
    ->where($qb->expr()->in('r.id', $qb2->getDQL()))

$rubrics = $qb1
    ->setParameter('id', $farmerId)
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
```

If you don't really need a `QueryBuilder` here, consider using plain DQL: as you see it's simpler.